# Display Text From a doc or docx file in a TextBox without using Microsoft.Office.Interop in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word

I want to display the text from a doc or docx file in a textbox.

Currently I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop to view the text but that needs MS Word to be installed on server. So I don't want to use that.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Microsoft Office Open XML SDK. That doesn't require MS Office be installed for creating or working with the contents of the document files.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb456487%28v=office.14%29.aspx

The SDK could be downloaded from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Comment: So I need to install Open XML SDK on my server. But I am not permitted to install anything on the server.

Comment: No. You have to include the dll in your project and that would be compiled in your project. Check this link about getting started with the SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb456488.aspx